# Get active Enumerations

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to list the members of arbitrary enumerations.  Is there a way to get a List of Enumerations or to get an Enumeration from its name, when that Name is a `String`?

Why?  The idea is to list the members of any chosen Enumeration in a Windows Form.  The specific enumeration to list might be nominated by entering its name into a `TextBox`; this would require a way to get the Enumeration Object from the `String` but VB.net does not appear to support this.  Alternatively, and perhaps better, the Enumeration could be picked from a list of Active Enumerations.  There are so many Enumerations in VB.Net that the listing idea would presumably need to restrict the list of `Enum` names to those that were, say, in use in the current application.  Can such a list be retrieved?

Comment: You can get type by it's name - `Type.GetType(nameOfSelectedType)` where `nameOfSelectedType` is a string.

Comment: What is your real goal here?  I can not imagine why an average end-user would ever know, need to know, or want to know the names of `Enum` types in .Net.  Your question title says "active Enumerations"; how do you define an "active enumeration"?

Comment: I agree that this seems like an odd request but, to answer the question as asked, you can get a `Type` object as suggested by @Fabio and then pass that to the `Enum.GetNames` or `Enum.GetValues` method.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio, I'll look at that as a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, jmcilhinney, that is what I planned but I could not find a way to get from text to the type object.  Fabio may have solved that.  Now if I could only get a list of all the ones in use in the current application I could make life easier - to answer TnTinMn - I've had to write my own VBA to VB.Net converter because Microsoft no longer supplies theirs.  This requires lists of the members of Enums so that Enum members can be detected in the old code and their names fully qualified during the conversion to VB.Net.

Comment: Sorry to take so long coming back a second time but I had a major system failure.  @Fabio's suggestion does not work.  This works in a limited way:
`Dim sEnMbr() As String = System.Enum.GetNames(GetType(Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle))`
But only because the Enumeration is specific, not generic.  It is not possible to use a string, nameOfSelectedType as @Fabio suggests.  I have tried using reflection to get a list of Enums but to no avail.  I can get a list of Assemblies but can't find my way to a list of Enums within those assemblies.  Can anyone suggest a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim enumType As Type = Type.GetType(enumTypeName)
Dim names = System.Enum.GetNames(enumType) 'working
```

Code above will work if `enumTypeName` is a "fullname" of the type
(for example `AssemblyName.YourEnum`)

```
Dim enumTypeFullName As String = GetType(YourEnum).FullName
Dim enumType As Type = Type.GetType(enumTypeName)
Dim names = System.Enum.GetNames(enumType) 'working
```

So if you using textbox for entering name of enum type, then you need input full name of enum or consider to use some predefined namespaces where you can search for given enum name

```
Function GetNamesByEnumTypeName(enumName As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim namespaces = New List(Of String) From
    {
        "Microsoft.VisualBasic",
        "System"
    }

    Dim foundedTypes = namespaces.Select(Function(ns) $"{ns}.{enumName}").
                                  Select(Function(fullName) Type.GetType(fullName)).
                                  Where(Function(enumType) enumType IsNot Nothing)

    For Each foundedType In foundedTypes
        Return System.Enum.GetNames(foundedType)
    Next

    Return Enumerable.Empty(Of String)
End Function
```